# Рекурсия для вывода чисел Фибоначчи

Tags: java, числа-фибоначчи

Нужно вывести требуемый член последовательности, при условии что первый член равен `1`, а второй - любое число с консоли.

Получается сделать через цикл, а как можно сделать через рекурсию?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int b = sc.nextInt();
    int c = sc.nextInt();
    int a = 1;
    int sum;

    void fibonacci() {
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            sum = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = sum;
            System.out.println("sum=" + sum);
        }
    }
}

public class JavaApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.fibonacci();
    }
}
```

Comment: Если второй член последовательности не `1`, то это уже не числа (последовательность) Фибоначчи, а просто линейная рекуррентная последовательность.

Comment: Да просто также как и в Фибоначчи каждое последующее число равно сумме двух предыдущих чисел.

Comment: Я понимаю. Проблема в том, что поверхностное чтение вопроса с таким заголовком может привести к закрытию вопроса как дубликата или к некорректным ответам, не учитывающим изменяемый второй член последовательности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С установкой значений первых двух элементов последовательности и использованием рекурсии получается так:

```
private static class MySequence
{
    private final int
            firstElement,
            secondElement;

    public MySequence(int firstElement, int secondElement)
    {
        this.firstElement = firstElement;
        this.secondElement = secondElement;
    }

    public int calculate(int index)
    {
        if (index <= 1)
            return firstElement;
        if (index == 2)
            return secondElement;
        return calculate(index - 1) + calculate(index - 2);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int firstElement = 1;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int secondElement = scanner.nextInt();
    int requiredElementIndex = scanner.nextInt();
    MySequence sequence = new MySequence(firstElement, secondElement);
    System.out.println(sequence.calculate(requiredElementIndex));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Приведу алгоритм получения `Fib(i)` за `O(logN)`.

Рассмотрим матрицу:

```
   | F0, F1 | = | 0 1 |  = One
   | F1, F2 |   | 1 1 |
```

Произведение матриц:

```
[ F(n-2), F(n-1) ] * One = [ F(n-1), F(n)]
```

показывает, что можно получить любое число Фибоначчи(Люка) возведя матрицу `One` в степень `N`.

Воспользовавшись алгоритмом быстрого возведения в степень, можно реализовать поиск n-го числа за `O(logN)`

При старте с матрицы `[0, 1]` мы получим широко известный ряд Фибоначчи, однако мы можем начать с любой пары чисел и получить любое [число Люка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%9B%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B0)

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Fib
{

  public static BigInteger[][] ONE = {{BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE}, {BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ONE}};
  public static BigInteger[][] mul(BigInteger[][] a, BigInteger[][] b) {
    BigInteger[][] res = {
      {a[0][0].multiply(b[0][0]).add(a[0][1].multiply(b[1][0])), a[0][0].multiply(b[0][1]).add(a[0][1].multiply(b[1][1]))},
      {a[1][0].multiply(b[0][0]).add(a[1][1].multiply(b[1][0])), a[1][0].multiply(b[0][1]).add(a[1][1].multiply(b[1][1]))}
    };
    return res;
  }
  public static BigInteger[][] pow(BigInteger[][] a, int k) {

    if (k == 0) return ONE;
    if (k == 1) return a;
    if (k == 2) return mul(a, a);
    if (k % 2 == 1) return mul(ONE, pow(a, k - 1));
    return pow(pow(a, k / 2), 2);
  }

  public static BigInteger LukNumber(int i0, int i1, int N) {
    if (N == 0) return BigInteger.valueOf(i0);
    BigInteger[][] P = pow(ONE, N);
    return BigInteger.valueOf(i0).multiply(P[0][0]).add(BigInteger.valueOf(i1).multiply(P[0][1]));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int secondNumber = 2;
    // Фибоначчи 0, 1, ..
    for (int i = 5; i < 10; ++i)
        System.out.println(i+": "+LukNumber(0, 1, i));

    for (int i = 5; i < 10; ++i)
        System.out.println(i+": "+LukNumber(1, secondNumber, i));
    System.out.println(1024+": "+LukNumber(1, secondNumber, 1024));
  }
}
```

Вывод:

> ```
> 5: 5       5: 13
> 6: 8       6: 21
> 7: 13      7: 34
> 8: 21      8: 55
> 9: 34      9: 89
> ```
>
> 1024: 
>   11798692818055232550147578884125865608089028544560913468519228968187430794620907976123201977895385245239705082830656904630178314159866370495211539023461052682811230321796555930907722724384131648527339458407317543768

---

*Сложно сказать, на каком размере задачи этот алгоритм превзойдёт линейный, потому что произведение матриц даёт довольно большую константу.*